# Persistent Id for my device in iOS which will with stand app uninstalls, factory reset and jailbroken scenarios

Tags: ios, swift, device, uninstallation, keychain

I want to have a persistent id for each device in ios irrespective of having multiple devices connected to single icloud <I want multiple persistent id's each for device>. and that should withstand app uninstalls, factory reset and jailbroken scenarios

I tried this below one by saving in keychain

```
import Foundation
import KeychainSwift

/// The `PersistentID` class generates and stores a persistent ID that can be used to identify a device.
class PersistentID {
    private let keychain = KeychainSwift()
    private let key = "persistentID"
    
    /// A unique identifier for the device, that is generated using a combination of `identifierForVendor` and `UUID`.
    var id: String {
        get {
            if let value = keychain.get(key) {
                return value
            } else {
                let newValue = UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor!.uuidString + UUID().uuidString
                keychain.set(newValue, forKey: key)
                return newValue
            }
        }
    }
    
    /**
    Initializes an instance of `PersistentID`.
    */
    init() {}
}
```

Comment: There is no identifier that can survive a device erase/factory reset.  You can use the DeviceCheck framework to permanently store 2 bits of data for a device, such as if it is blacklisted. If you want to store a value in keychain you can just use a uuid. There isn't any point in adding identifierForVendor.

Comment: You need to push this UUID to the server mapped with associated account. So that in case of erase, post login you can fetch the UUID for that user and check if that Device is same.